# Problems with scope

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to assign a handler to every child element that I loop over. My problem is that the: `target = child.items[i].id;` will have the id of the last element that I loop over. So this part:

```
    fn: function() {
        isoNS.injectKey(target);
    }
```

will always have the the id (target) of the last child. How can I do this? 
I have tried put `this` in front, like this: `isoNS.injectKey(this.target);`

```
var arr=[];

for(var i = 0; i < obj.items.length; ++i) {
    target = child.items[i].id;
    arr.push({
        key: sHolder.charAt(i),
        fn: function() {
            isoNS.injectKey(target);
        },
    });
}
```

So my main problem, is that each different value of: `target = child.items[i].id;` is overwritten with the latest element each time. I hope I am making myself understood.

In case you are wondering what obj and child is... I left them out to make the code shorter and more understandable. just know that they do have values in them, and are never null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with closures:

```
var arr=[];

function getFunc(t){ 
          return function() {
            isoNS.injectKey(t);
        }};

for(var i = 0; i < obj.items.length; ++i) {
    target = child.items[i].id;
    arr.push({
        key: sHolder.charAt(i),
        fn: getFunc(target),
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this

```
var arr = Array.prototype.map.call(obj.items, function(obj, i) {
    return {
        key: sHolder.charAt(i),
        fn: function() {
            isoNS.injectKey(child.items[i].id);
        }
    };
});
```

the `Array` `map` function provides the closure, and a nicer way to build up your `arr`

I use `Array.prototype.map.call` because there's no indication if obj.items is a TRUE array ... if it is, then it's a bit simpler

```
var arr = obj.items.map(function(obj, i) {
    return {
        key: sHolder.charAt(i),
        fn: function() {
            isoNS.injectKey(child.items[i].id);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your function is a closure and it has captured a reference to the target variable and this gets changed by your loop before the call back is invoked.  A simple way to get around this is to wrap your function in another closure that captures the value of the target variable.

You can do this like so:

```
(function(capturedValue){
    return function () {
        // do something with the capturedValue
    };
}(byRefObject));
```

The first function is part of an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE).  It serves to capture the value of the byRefObject.  You can read more about IIFE [here](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Your code could look like this:

```
var arr=[];

for(var i = 0; i < obj.items.length; ++i) {
    target = child.items[i].id;
    arr.push({
        key: sHolder.charAt(i),
        fn: (function(target) {
                return function() {
                    isoNS.injectKey(target);
                };
             })(target)
        },
    });
}
```